# Rendering a table where each cell correspond to an element with material-ui in React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I need to make a table where each product corresponds to a cell; however, there's something with the JSX that prevents me from returning jsx when I don't close the tags in the returned JSX. I am not sure if there are alternate methods, but it seems that I am in a kind of bind, because the error message doesn't make sense and I get things like unexpected token.

Tried to return the JSX with map inside the callback, but it seems I can't do exactly what I want.

```
       {props.products.slice(0, 50).map((element, i) => {
          console.log(element.name);
          if (i % 5 == 0) {
            return (
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>{element.name}</TableRowColumn>
            )

          } else if (i % 5 == 4) {

            return (
                <TableRowColumn>{element.name}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            )

          } else {

            return (
                <TableRowColumn>{element.name}</TableRowColumn>
            )

          }

        })}
```

I expect each row to have 5 columns, and each cell containing a product and the table containing 50 elements. Basically, I want to close the row after 5 column.

I would like to have something like a 5 by 5 table in the end or 5 by 10 to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check some examples on material-ui site (https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/)

If you know which elements are headers names you can use for-loop over products to create columns name e.g.

```
<TableRow>
  {props.products.map((product, index) => {
    if (index % 5 === 0) {
      return <TableCell>{product.name}</TableCell>;
    }
  }
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Just adapt it, very simple

Comment: I think the only solution is to iterate by chunks of 5.

Comment: It looks really similar in v0:
<TableHeader>
      <TableRow>
        {props.products.map((product, index) => {
          if (index % 5 === 0) {
            return <TableHeaderColumn >{product.name}</TableHeaderColumn>;
        }
       }        
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>

Comment: Also, you didn't understand the question. I want to create a 5 by 5 table and do it in a single loop. I am not trying to create a 1 by 5 row column headers. Maybe, I should have clarified.

Comment: I understand your question. First you need to create headers, then in similar way you can iterate over your data and render rows.

Comment: I don't have headers though. It's like a table of image without column header, that's why the solution won't work. One thing I realized though is that I only need headers at the top. I shouldn't have used headers, is there a way to do this with 1 loop and without headers?

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not HTML and you cannot brake up tag pairs.

Proper solution should be like this

```
function chunker(array, length) {
   // select proper implementation on the link below
   return []
}
{chunker(props.products.slice(0, 50)), 5).map((chunk) => {
  if (chunk.length !== 5) {
    console.warn('not full chunk', chunk)
  }
  return (
    <TableRow>
      {chunk.map((element, i) => {
        console.log(element.name);
        return (
          <TableRowColumn>{element.name}</TableRowColumn>
        )
      })}
    </TableRow>
  )
})}
```

Select chunk implementation here [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: Looks like it is missed. Please check proper method here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: uncaught at g Error: e.slice(...).chunk is not a function. Yeah, I looked at that page earlier, but I didn't want to create chunks or create a method or use a library just for this.

Comment: @tefisjb Sorry, I was confused by usage of https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638192/6625548

Comment: It's ok, I am pretty sure the only way is to use a chunk method or a for loop and iterate by chunk.